# How do I get new missions from Martin Madrazo?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I can't get new missions from Martin Madrazo. I really want to try Holed Up by him and Bust Out from Lester, but I can never get them when I call them!

Answer (score 2):

There are 5 ways that I know of to take part in a job:

1. Randomly delivered to your phone.
2. Using the Quick Job feature on your phone.
3. Calling a contact and requesting a job.
4. Finding the job in the world and entering the blue circle.
5. Pausing, going to "Online" and beginning a job from the menus there.

To do what you're trying to do, the only thing that might help you at this point might be option 5. I don't use it all that often so I can't say whether or not the specific jobs you're looking for are listed in there, but hopefully they are.